# Linux Bash auto command, source text file

Tags: linux, bash

Thank you for your concern.
I'm a noob trying to bulk-ip-lookup with [geoiplookup -f GeoLiteCity.dat] command.

I have more than 700 ips to lookup which saved on as c.txt (on the same folder)
How can I make a bash shell script? I've already made one and all I got was:

```
sudo: unable to execute ./ok.sh: No such file or directory
```

Here is my script

[image]

It would be all - ok to use another language.

```
To make it more clear;
[geoiplookup -f GeoLiteCity.dat IP1]
[geoiplookup -f GeoLiteCity.dat IP2]
             ...
[geoiplookup -f GeoLiteCity.dat IP700]
and save them as one text file. (Which would be 700 row)
```

I'm Korean and sorry for my poor English, but I couldn't find any in my language how to do this. I'll really appreciate it, or I have to look up 1 by 1 till Friday... (as internet speed is extremely slow in my company)

Please help me. I will pray for you at every sunday morning. Thank you.

Comment: Did you make `ok.sh` executable? For example: `chmod a+x ok.sh`?

Comment: it keep says bash: ./ok.sh /usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Thank you kaylum. I've tried the chmod and afterward it keep argues no such file...T^T

Comment: Are you sure bash is installed in /usr/bin? What does `which  bash` tell you?

Comment: sorry kaylum. due to electronic issue, I got anther computer to use. (which has lower cpu than before) and just checked it now; i will install linux again soon

Comment: Isn't it pre-installed when ubuntu installed?

Comment: I'm really sorry kaylum,.. Couldn't keep in touch;;; It was ME who asked.. sorry for your time...I'll try another version, and it is too rude asking another question again and again i guess. god bless you.

Answer (score 1):

found a very simple answer with a duckduckgo search for 'iterate through each line of file bash'
stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash

```
  #!/usr/bin/bash

  printf "\n\n"

  while read ip; do
          echo "LOOKING UP IP $ip"
          geoiplookup $ip
          printf "\n\n"
  done < ipaddresses.txt
```

save it as iplookup.sh and run, without 'sudo':

```
    bash iplookup.sh
```

tested and working. be sure to rename your file 'c.txt' to 'ipaddresses.txt' ! also the 'ipaddresses.txt' file must be in the same directory